# Linux: How to remap Capslock to a Function key?

Tags: linux, keyboard, remapping

How can I remap the CapsLock key to a Function key on Linux? When I search this up I can only find how to remap the CapsLock key to a Control key but not to a Function key.

Comment: Every key board I have seen (even before computers) has a Caps Lock key. Why not use the correct key?